# Method use limitations

Tags: java, code-access-security

I was wondering if there is a way to stop one class from using a method but let another use the method depending on what they extend.

Lets say class1 implements Plugin and class2 implements Mod, is it possible to allow class2 to use method load(); but stop class1 from using it

Comment: Beyond checking the caller type, this is hard to do. But often that is also not really necessary. If you tell us the context, maybe we can suggest better solutions.

Comment: You can overload the method and make the restricted method version do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can pass the type of the caller to the method and then use the [instanceof comparison operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html). For example:

```
public void myMethod(Object obj){
    if(obj instanceof Mod){
        \\ do something
    } else if(obj instanceof Plugin){
        \\ do not permit
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **instanceof** to check the type of instance, and then give it the permission to method.

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
Class2 c2 = new Class2();

doIt(c1);
doIt(c2);

public void doIt(Object obj){

    if (obj instanceof Class2){

         myRestrictedMethod();

    }


}
```

Comment: I don;t like the idea of doing this, this could cause a security issue

Comment: It would be nice, if you can point out the security concern you have

Comment: This solution won't work if stuff is called by reflection. The checks must happen in the method that is restricted.

Comment: Ya thats right...but apart reflection, this works right.... and yes thanks for pointing out the security issue...